# WP7 environment for QA

Tags: download, emulation, windows-phone-7

I have to setup windows phone 7 emulator & application deployment on QA machine.

plz guide me in this regard. I want the minimum software to be install there.

Can it be possible on XP SP3 or not?

it will be helpfull if someone provide the download link

Comment: any idea............................?

Answer (score 0):

You will need..

1) Windows Phone Developer registration tool, so that u can register your device b4 testing the app on it. 
2) Application deployment tool ,to deploy the xap file on the device and emulator.
to install the above tools u will have to install windows phone developer tools

3) Zune software.

for 1 and 2 follow this link : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13890 
please follow the requirements specified there.You need to have **windows vista SP1 or above OS**

and for 3 follow : http://www.zune.net/en-us/products/software/download/default.htm

Comment: like shows that it will install the following;                                                                                                                                                                           The Windows Phone Developer Tools includes the following

(1)Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone (no use for QA)
(2)Windows Phone Emulator Resources
(3)Silverlight 4 Tools For Visual Studio  (no use for QA)
(4)XNA Game Studio 4.0
(5)Microsoft Expression Blend for Windows Phone  (no use for QA) I only want to set up minimum things on the QA machine

Comment: U need all the three for QA testing.As far as i know these are the minimum requirements.